# What is the right html structure for a modal navigation menu

Tags: html, dom, menu, navigation

What is the correct html structure for a modal menu?

That behaves similar to the code below.

I would like to use the `dialog` tag since this provides all the modal functionality that I believe I need, but the menu functionality doesn't fit the dialog semantics.

```js
const modalBtn = document.getElementById("modalBtn");
const modal = document.querySelector("div");
const closeBtn = document.getElementById("closeBtn");

modalBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background: hotpink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<button id="modalBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="closeBtn">Close</button>
</div>
```